# If custom channel field entry exists display content else display alternate content

Tags: conditionals, ifelse

I am trying to set up a slider in ExpressionEngine which will display a video if the video embed code exists, otherwise it will display an image slider. Currently, I am not able to hide the image slider if the video code exists(but the video does get placed on the page).

Here is my code:

```
{slider}
    {if video}
            {video}
    {if:else}
        {if total_rows > "1" && row_count == "1"}
            <div id='news_slider'>
        {/if}
            <img title="{img_title}" src="{img}" />
        {if total_rows > "1" && row_count == total_rows}
            </div>
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/slider}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this? The difference is on Line 2. It does mean you're running the conditional against the entire embed string rather than the variable but it may work.

```
{slider}
    {if "{video}"!=""}
            {video}
    {if:else}
        {if total_rows > "1" && row_count == "1"}
            <div id='news_slider'>
        {/if}
            <img title="{img_title}" src="{img}" />
        {if total_rows > "1" && row_count == total_rows}
            </div>
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/slider}
```

I also found out from the OP that this is running EE 2.5.5 and Pixel and Tonic Matrix. I wrote a prototype alternative in Grid and advised he upgrades to that.

Comment: Hmmm it seems like if I do it that way ExpressionEngine is treating the raw embed code as the conditional variable. I am getting: "Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable"

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: So instead of checking if "video" is set, it's checking if "<iframe width="560" height="315"...." is set.

Basically it's treating the raw embed code as the variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Currently I have a single channel field called "Slider" which has the options of "img_title," "image" and "video." Would it make more sense to set up the video as it's own channel field and then do the conditional statement that way, or is it possible to achieve using a single channel field like I am now? Thanks for the help Andrew!

Comment: What kind of field is this?

Comment: It's a matrix field

Comment: Let me have a play and I'll get back to you in 5.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13559/discussion-between-andrew-fairlie-and-apad1)